# beamer caption does not appear

Tags: beamer, floats, captions

I would like to write the caption below a figure but unfortunately the caption does not appear when I compile the tex. The Figure is ok, but I would like to see below the figure smth like "Figure 1: bla bla". I attach below a MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}


\usepackage{caption} 
\usepackage{subcaption}
%\usepackage{floatrow}
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2}
\small\normalsize

\newcommand{\beginbackup}{
    \newcounter{framenumbervorappendix}
    \setcounter{framenumbervorappendix}{\value{framenumber}}
}
\newcommand{\backupend}{
    \addtocounter{framenumbervorappendix}{-\value{framenumber}}
    \addtocounter{framenumber}{\value{framenumbervorappendix}} 
}


\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{mini frames}{}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[ball]
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}[ball]
\setbeamercovered{invisible}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\title{Write Title Here}   
\author{Author name}     


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}

\frametitle{Title here}   

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{Fig/myfigure}
    \caption{Write here figure caption}
    \label{fig1}
\end{figure}


\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add to your document preamble `\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]`:

```
\documentclass[demo]{beamer} % in real document remove option "demo"
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]   % NEW

\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{mini frames}{}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[ball]
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}[ball]
\setbeamercovered{invisible}

\usepackage{subcaption}
%\usepackage{floatrow}
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2}
\small\normalsize
\newcommand{\beginbackup}{
    \newcounter{framenumbervorappendix}
    \setcounter{framenumbervorappendix}{\value{framenumber}}
}
\newcommand{\backupend}{
    \addtocounter{framenumbervorappendix}{-\value{framenumber}}
    \addtocounter{framenumber}{\value{framenumbervorappendix}}
}
\title{Write Title Here}
\author{Author name}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Title here}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{Fig/myfigure}
    \caption{Write here figure caption}
    \label{fig1}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]